# How could I Cut & Paste a found range of not blank cells from a column beginning from the 10th row?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, header

Every day, I receive an Excel file with a variable amount of rows and columns with different headers.

A macro copies all the information in a sheet, rearranges the columns in a specific order and deletes the columns I don't need.

The problem is to copy the raw information at the 10th row (header) and execute the macro. The rows above the 10th row are affected as well and I need them unchanged.

I tried to find the solution, but even if I am close I don't get it.

```
Dim search As Range

Dim counter As Integer

Dim lines As Integer

Dim columnOrder As Variant

Dim position As Integer

'define column order with header names here
columnOrder = Array("ID", "HOUR EXP", "FIRM ORG", "TRADER")

counter = 1

'I want here count how many rows with data are there
lines = Cells(Rows.Count, 10).End(xlUp).Row

'LBound/Ubound indicates how many total headers are there
For position = LBound(columnOrder) To UBound(columnOrder)

    Set search = Rows("10:10").Find(columnOrder(position), _
      LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
      SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)

    If Not search Is Nothing Then
        If search.Column <> counter Then

        search.EntireColumn.Cut
        Columns(counter).Insert Shift:=xlToRight

        '-->I'm trying (unsucessfully) here to select only from the found column 
        ' the range beggining at row 10 with various possibilities 
        'search.Range(Rows("10:" & lines + 10)).Cut 
        'search.EntireColumn.Cut                          
        'Rows(contador).Insert Shift:=xlToRight                             
        'Cells(contador).Insert Shift:=xlToRight                

        Application.CutCopyMode = False

        End If

        counter = counter + 1

    End If
Next position

Worksheets("sheet1").ActivateRange("E10", Range("E10").End(xlToRight).End(xlDown)).Delete
End Sub
```

Comment: First step: change all instances of `Integer` to `Long`.

Comment: `Search` is a worksheet function, use something else. For inserting a blank block without affecting the top 10 rows try this: `Range(mysearch.Offset(1, 0), Cells(mysearch.Row + 100, mysearch.Column)).Insert shift:=xlToRight

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thx for the idea @AcsErno. With this I figured it out. I just needed to use OffSet in order to do not affect first 9 rows

```
Range(search.Offset(0, 0), Cells(search.Row + lines - 1, search.Column)).Cut
Cells(counter).Offset(rowOffset:=9, columnOffset:=0).Activate
ActiveCell.Insert shift:=xlToRight Application.CutCopyMode = False 
End If 
counter = counter + 1 
End If

Next position
```